# When submit is pressed, the left icon of the button changes to Loading ajax icon using fontawesome

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, font-awesome

Please help to solve such problem.

There is `submit-button`, that is decorated by icon. How it is possible to make icon's changes using `ajax` and `fontawesome`? When submit is pressed, the left icon changes to Loading ajax icon and `send button` is disabled. When `ajax response error`, then show error icon, and `send" button` is enable, show error message. If `success`: show checkmark icon.

Part of html:

```
<pre>
    <div id="#form-submit" class="field decoration clearfix submit">
        <a href="" class="button add">Submit</a>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Part for css:

```
.button:before {
  background: #ccc;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  float: left;
  .....
}

.add:before {
  content: "\2709";
}
```

I try to make such structure for ajax, is it right?

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      beforeSend:function(xhr,opts){
        $(".button:before").append('<i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
      },
      success(function(){
         $(".button:before").append('<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
       },
       .error(function(){
         $(".button:before").append('<i class="fa fa-exclamation" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
       },
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add a `i` tag to add icon to your button and let it have a class as `fa fa-send` as below.

```
<pre>
    <div id="#form-submit" class="field decoration clearfix submit">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button add"><i class="fa fa-send"> </i> Submit</a>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Now you can change the class for `icon` as below:

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _ctrl=$(this);
    _ctrl.find('i').removeClass('fa-send').addClass('fa-spinner').attr('disabled',true);
    $.ajax({
      url:url,
      type:'GET',
      success:function(){
         _ctrl.find('i').removeClass('fa-spinner').addClass('fa-check');
       },
       error:function(){
         _ctrl.find('i').removeClass('fa-spinner').addClass('fa-send').attr('disabled',false);
       },
   });
});
```

**Note - You don't need `beforeSend` `ajax` Option for these kind of stuffs, unless you have some operations to do within it, because you can change icon as soon as you click the button. You have few problem in your `ajax`structure which has been corrected**